# how to discard a branch in Xcode source control

Tags: xcode, github, branching-and-merging

I have a large project in Xcode and have created a branch via source-control for developing an idea I had, however the concept is not successful so I would like to abandon the branch altogether and go back to the point just before i branched. What procedure should I follow and what are the risks along the way? I need to do this flawlessly.

```
A1_A2_A3_______ I would like to revert to A3
       \__B1_B2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 5 choose Source Control > Working Copies > Switch to Branch to switch back to branch A3. The Working Copies menu item will have the name of your project and the current branch.

To remove branches B1 and B2, choose Source Control > Working Copies > Configure. A sheet opens. Click the Branches button to show all the branches in the repository. Select a branch and click the minus button to remove it.

[image]